# How to sort a javascript array numerically twice

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of bible verses that i'm trying to order according to the natural order of verses.

The array looks like this:

```
let array = ["1.2","1.3","1.19","2.25","1.0"]
```

What i'm expecting as end result is:

```
1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.19, 2.25
```

Any pointers welcome, I haven't quite managed to come up with the perfect sort function that sorts the first digit before sorting everything else on the opposite end of the decimal.

My current approach that needs to be improved I believe is:

```
x.sort(function(a,b){

let y = a.split(".")[1]
let x = b.split(".")[1]

return a-b && y - x;
})
```

Comment: What exactly isn’t working with your current approach? Seems to work just fine. Can you include an example where the sort function fails?

Comment: thanks @Xufox, what approach is giving you the expected result I posted above?

Comment: Well, I just copy-pasted the array and your sort function into the console and tried it: `let array = [`…`];`, then `array.sort(`…`);` with your sort function should already work. Otherwise, please include the actual result that you get as well.

Comment: However, I’ll just add that it’s weird that you put an `&&` in there. I’d do it with `||`. Specifically: `return a.split(".")[0] - b.split(".")[0] || a.split(".")[1] - b.split(".")[1]`. Basically, it’s `return (first sorting criterion) || (second sorting criterion);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let array = ["1.2","1.3","1.19","2.25","1.0"];

// split the number into the integer part and decimal part
splits = array.map(x => ({
  val: x,
  int: Number(x.split(".")[0]),
  dec: Number(x.split(".")[1])
  }));
        
splits.sort(function(a, b) {
    // compare the integer part first, if equal, compare decimal part
    return (a.int === b.int)?(a.dec - b.dec):(a.int - b.int);
    });
    
sorted = splits.map(x => x.val);
console.log(sorted);
```

Another option to sort array in place:

```js
let array = ["1.2","1.3","1.19","2.25","1.0"];

array.sort(function(a, b) {

  a_split = a.split(".").map(Number);
  b_split = b.split(".").map(Number);

  return (a_split[0] === b_split[0])?(a_split[1] - b_split[1]):(a_split[0] - b_split[0]);
})

console.log(array);
```

Comment: You could also `return a.int - b.int || a.dec - b.dec;` or `return a_split[0] - b_split[0] || a_split[1] - b_split[1];`.